# Unfix child div

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed div that sticky to the top on scrolling. But the child div shouldn't be fixed. Is there a way to do it without change the html structure?

```
<div id="header" style="position: fixed; top: 0">
   <div id="shouldn't_be_sticky" style="position: absolute">
        some content
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: position: fixed; top: 0 you set a "," instead a ";" !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

According to [this (MDN specification)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning), the absolutely positioned element is positioned relative *to nearest positioned ancestor*, which has fixed positioning, and child element will be sticked to it.

So you have to change your html.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but what you can do is not nesting it:

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
<div id="shouldn't_be_sticky" style="position: absolute;">
  some content
</div>
```